# web exception was unhandled by user code. Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: asp.net

i'm able to hit the uri "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Bangalore' from my browser.

But when i'm trying to call the same from asp.net getting error. code is below.

```
    string url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Bangalore";
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        string json = client.DownloadString(url);

        WeatherInfo weatherInfo = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<WeatherInfo>(json);
    }
```

**Error is - "Unable to connect to the remote server".**

what could be the reason?

Comment: i found the problem - I missed proxy. After passing proxy it worked.

Comment: client.Proxy = new WebProxy("your proxy");